# WordPress plugin/script for interactive element that shows steps/stages

Tags: wordpress

I am building a website that needs an element to show steps/stages.

I need something like in the [bottom part of this page](http://www.ghidinirodil.com/en/servicios/) where it says "Metodologia" in a circle.

I am using WordPress so a plugin can do, but any script/library or way to create web elements like this will help.